# Pasar datos a diferentes componentes desde event bus - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Holaaa a todos! Estoy intentado pasar un dato entre diferentes componentes (paginas) en vue. La pagina es SPA

Tengo 3 paginas. En la primera estan las opciones de diferentes planes para comprar. Luego de elegir el plan, pasa a la segunda pagina, y de ella, pasa a la tercera pagina, en el cual se realiza el pago. Si quiere cambiar el plan, en la tercera pagina tiene un boton para ir a la primera y seleccionar el plan. A esta primera pagina, me gustaria pasarle algun flag para avisarle que se salte la segunda pagina. Sin realizar queries en la URL

Para realizar esto. Lo primero que hice fue utilizar un event bus. En la tercera pagina cuando hace click en el boton, llama a un metodo, ejecuta el evento y hace un push a la primera pagina.

La primera pagina escucha el evento, y asigna un nuevo valor a un data 'routeNext'.

El boton de la primera pagina se enlaza a esta variable para ir a la segunda o tercera pagina.

El codigo:

Pagina 1

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 class="mt-0" style="font-size: 16px">Elige el plan</h1>
        </div>


        <div>
          <router-link :to="{name: route}">Continuar</router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import EventBus from "../event_bus";

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          routeNext: "page2"
        };
      },

      created() {
        console.log(this.routeNext); ==> page2
        EventBus.$on("change", () => {
          this.routeNext = "payment";
        console.log(this.routeNext); ==> payment
        });
        console.log(this.routeNext); ==> page2
      },

      computed: {
        route() {
          return this.routeNext;
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Pagina 2

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 class="mt-0" style="font-size: 16px">Confirma tu pago</h1>
        </div>

        <p>Puedes cancelar cuando quieras</p>

        <div>
          <router-link :to="{name: 'payment'}">Continuar</router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Pagina 3

```
    <template>
      <div>
          <div>
            <div>Tu plan</div>

            <span>{{ plan}}</span>

            <button type="button" @click="changePlan">Cambiar</button>
          </div>

            <!-- FORMULARIO -->

      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import EventBus from "../event_bus";

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          plan: []
        };
      },

      methods: {
        changePlan: function () {
            EventBus.$emit('change');
            this.$router.push({name: 'page1'});
        }
      },
    };
    </script>
```

El problema que tengo es que luego de escuchar el evento, no asigna el valor a 'routeNext'. He probado colocando un console.log para verificar el valor de routeNext dentro del evento y lo que pasa es que asigna el nuevo valor, pero al salir le vuelve a colocar el anterior que tenia, es decir 'page2'.

En la consola me sale lo siguiente.

page2 
payment 
page2

Page2 es el primer valor que tiene, luego escucha el evento, le asigna 'payment' y al salir, le asigna devuelta 'page2'

Como puedo hacer para asignar el valor?

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos deberías utilizar [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org),ayuda bastante en estos casos, permitiendo compartir variables y funciones entre componentes totalmente independientes.

De todas formas, tu error me parece que está en la función que le pasas al evento, el `this` hace referencia a esa función en vez de al componente, puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
 created() {
        const self = this; // guardamos el this en una constante
        EventBus.$on("change", () => {
          self.routeNext = "payment"; // reverenciamos al componente
        }); 
 },
```

Y digo me parece por que no puedo ejecutarlo, para estos casos deberías publicar un mínimo reproducible de tu código. Por que por más que nuestra experiencia nos permita detectar errores a la vista, es más sencillo si lo probamos.

Por último, otro detalle, que espero que te hayas dado cuenta, pero de todas formas lo aclararé, en tus `console.log()`, el tercero se ejecuta antes del segundo, recuerda que el segundo se ejecuta al momento de que se lanza el evento, no al momento de agregar el evento.